# Using a TSA lock or not

Tags: luggage, domestic-travel

My new luggage has tsa lock which I thought naively was a good thing.  But having second thought after reading other's experiences.  Nothing valuable in my bag, have free baggage check-in, just will zipper it all like I always did on short flight and forget about the tsa lock.  Had a brief moment of "stress" just thinking about what "if" I can't open it.  Travelling twice a year  is stressful, why add another component.  Has anyone else made  similar decision?  just zip it?

Answer (score 2):

One advantage of the TSA locks is that it is easy to get spare keys for them. Look at the number on the lock (should be TSA00n with n between 1 and 7) and then search ebay for keys.

Or go to https://github.com/Xyl2k/TSA-Travel-Sentry-master-keys where you can download the files to print a key yourself (or have someone print one for you).

Comment: Oh great - if my case is lost or stolen at least I know the thief or person finding it will be able to open it :-(

Comment: Yes. TSA locks aren't really locks. I usually now put zipties on... I want to know if my case has been opened in transit. I am not worried about theft as all that is in my luggage is clothes, toiletries and a spare phone/laptop charger.

Comment: Like @Krist, I also use zip ties rather than locks. But, there is one notable advantage to using a lock, which is that it will continue to keep the luggage securely closed even after the TSA or other agency decides they want to open your luggage. They will cut a zip tie but won't replace it. How important this is depends on how much you trust the baggage handlers to not accidentally (or even "accidentally") open your luggage during handling.